# differences between 2 api's angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I've to call this API:

http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters/house/slytherin

and I was doing a tutorial that use this API:

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

The tutorial link works, but when I tried to replace the link I don't retrieve anything, this is the code:

The Service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { User } from "./user.model";

@Injectable()
export class HelloWooService {
  apiUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  get_users() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }
}
```

The Component

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{ name }}!</h1>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      h1 {
        font-family: Lato;
      }
    `
  ]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class HelloWooService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  getPosts() {
    return this.httpClient.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
  }
}
```

The Model

```
export class User {
  name: string;
  gender: string;
  dateOfBirth: Date;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div *ngFor='let item of users$' style="text-align:center">
  <h2>{{item.name}} - {{item.dateOfBirth}}</h2>
</div>
```

[With the tutorial API the page show this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yt9w.png)

[And with the API that i want show's nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUHq1.png)

[Network to question request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3nmT.png)

I'm only changing this:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { User } from "./user.model";

@Injectable()
export class HelloWooService {
  apiUrl = "http://hp-api.herokuapp.com/api/characters/house/slytherin";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  get_users() {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }
}
```

I'm a newbie don't kill me

EDIT:
[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTkgC.png)
[Network Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIMT9.png)

Comment: Would you please attach the screenshot of the network tab which displays your API call in your inspect element?

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's attached now

Comment: Just an fyi both gender and dateOfBirth is not in the response of that api data

Comment: I also dont see in that image you attached the api call being done.

Comment: In the third photo, we can see "(blocked:mix...". What's the full message? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Gender and DateOfBirth are part of the respond that i need to show is in the API of slytherin

Comment: Can you share the errors in console? Or you can click on the last request of the network tab marked as red and share that screenshot also.

Comment: blocked:mixed content i will add the console errors give me a second

Comment: Ready the console and the network errors are attached

Comment: Just change your API URL to secure HTTPS protocol. Change http with https.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the api over https it also looks like you calling the old url and not the one you intended too

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your API URL over HTTPS.